# Why can't add I Motion Graphics Templates to Premiere Pro 2020 Timeline

Tags: premiere

So basically, the issue I am running into is as described in the subject. I am trying to add a motion graphics template that I made in Adobe After Effects 2020 and installed to Adobe Premiere Pro 2020. I simply can't add it. Premiere won't let me add it to the timeline. I've tried adding other templates that come with Premiere and those don't work either. I am really new to Adobe Premiere and other Adobe products so I must just not know something simple.

My basic system specs are: Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz, 3601 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s), OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Home, Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB, Total Physical Memory 15.9 GB, Available Physical Memory 8.12 GB, Total Virtual Memory 25.6 GB, Available Virtual Memory 15.5 GB.

I have attached a link to a video file showing me trying to add the different templates and failing. Let me know if I should add anything else.

[loom video link to me trying to add mogrts](https://www.loom.com/share/f6bc6278aeb84204940c4098a8ba46ef)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Sorry about this, but video editing questions are [off-topic here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). So, I've flagged this for migration to Video Production Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with MOGRT too much but I assume this is similar to working with AEP comps that you live-edit within Premiere.

Try either dropping into the project first, then into timeline.
Try rolling back to last 'main' version of both AE and PP - so still using 2020 but e.g from 14.5 to 14.0 - often issues appear with PP/AE mismatch during small updates and dynamiclink can be unpredictable.
Hope this helps

Answer (score -4):

[image]

Do exactly as shown
You need to create a new sequence
And drag and drop the motion graphics file into it